# Globally available of spfx web part sharepoint online

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I would like to create a web part that is available on every page and sub site inside SharePoint online. Example is the Wizdom PowerPanel. It's available on every site on the left.

Anybody an idea about how to create this?